# Assembler OR operation

Tags: assembly, c++

Is this asm code:

```
or      unknown_byte_0004AAA7, 1

dseg05:000C7FDC unknown_byte_0004AAA7 db 0
```

equivalent to this C++ code below?

```
bool unknown_byte_0004AAA7 = 0;
unknown_byte_0004AAA7 = unknown_byte_0004AAA7 | 1;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Almost, but not exactly. `bool` is not required to be 1 byte long in C++, so I'd declare `unknown_byte_0004AAA7` as `uint8_t`, to make sure it is one byte long.